# how can I instruct Eclipse to search for my AndroidManifest.xml file in another folder?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

I would like to configure Eclipse to search the AndroidManifest.xml file in another location than the default one.

My current location for AndroidManifest.xml is in src/main and Eclipse is expecting the file in the root project.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the ADT plugin for Eclipse expects AndroidManifest.xml to be in the root folder.

I just created a symbolic link in the root folder (in linux) that points to the actual AndroidManifest.xml located at `APP_ROOT/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`. I did the same for the `res` directory so I could build the project in eclipse using native Gradle directory layout for the project.

Comment: This could actually work.. too bad I didn't think of it in the past. 

In the meantime I gave up using both Eclipse/maven and IntelliJ/Gradle and I use only Eclipse/Maven. In the future I might try once again to move to Gradle but for the moment I'm pretty happy with Eclipse.

I will accept your answer even though I cannot test it.